# SelectKBest with GaussianNB not precise/consistent results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I want to select **top K features** using `SelectKBest` and run `GaussianNB`:

```
selection = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=300)

data_transformed = selection.fit_transform(data, labels)
new_data_transformed = selection.transform(new_data)

classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(data_transformed, labels)
y_predicted = classifier.predict(new_data)
acc = accuracy_score(new_data_labels, y_predicted)
```

However, I do not get consistent results for accuracy on the same data.
The accuracy has been:

```
0.61063743402354853
0.60678034916768164 
0.61733658140479086 
0.61652456354039786 
0.64778725131952908 
0.58384084449857898
```

For the SAME data. I don't do splits etc. I just use two static sets of `data` and `new_data`.

**Why do the results vary? How do I make sure I get the same accuracy for the same data?**

Answer (score 2):

This is because their is some randomness in the data or variables. This depends on the **Random number generator** used internally by the estimators or functions, in your case it is [`mutual_info_classif`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif) which you pass into `SelectKBest`.

Have a look at the usage of `random_state` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42197534/3374996)

As a workaround you can insert the following line on top of your code.

```
np.random.seed(some_integer)
```

This will set the numpy's seed to the `some_integer` and as far as I know, scikit estimators uses numpy's random number generator. [See this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057197/should-i-use-random-seed-or-numpy-random-seed-to-control-random-number-gener)