# Saving order of splitting with a vector of index

Tags: python, numpy, split, scikit-learn

l want to split data into train and test and also a vector that contains names (it serves me as an index and reference).

```
name_images has a shape of (2440,)
```

My data are :

```
data has a shape of (2440, 3072) 
labels has a shape of (2440,)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.3)
```

but l want also to split my `name_images` into `name_images_train` and `name_images_test` with respect to the split of `data` and `labels`

l tried

```
  x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test,name_images_train,name_images_test= train_test_split(data, labels,name_images, test_size=0.3)
```

it doesn't preserve the order 
Any suggestions 
thank you

EDIT1:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(data, labels,test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

name_images_train, name_images_test=train_test_split(name_images, 
                                                         test_size=0.3, 
                                                         random_state=42)
```

`EDIT1` don't preserve the order

Comment: I am not understanding. You want to preserve order each time you call this `train_test_split`, or do you want to preserve the order of splitting of `data`,  `labels` and `name_images` during the same call to `train_test_split`?

Comment: l want to preserve the order of splitting of data, labels and name_images during the same call

Comment: That is what my answer does. That means that if train_X gets index [1,5,7..] then train_y and name_images_train will also get the same indices. If that still dont fit your need, can you give an example of what output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

The most straight forward is to use `random_state` parameter of `train_test_split`. As the [documentation states](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split):

> random_state : **int or RandomState** :-
>       Pseudo-random number generator state used for random sampling.

When you fix the random_state, the indices which are generated for splitting the arrays into train and test are exact same each time.

So change your code to:

```
x_train, x_test, 
y_train, y_test, 
name_images_train, name_images_test=train_test_split(data, labels, name_images, 
                                                     test_size=0.3, 
                                                     random_state=42)
```

For more understanding on random_state, see my answer here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42197534/3374996

Comment: l tried also the following but it doesn't work : x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, name_images_train, name_images_test=train_test_split(data_pixels, classes, images_names, 
                                                     test_size=0.3, 
                                                     random_state=42)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I realize that my input arrays were not in proper order in the first place. So for future Googlers--you may want to double-check if `(data, labels)` are in the same order or not.