# Whats the significance of random_state in train_test_split?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What's the significance of **random_state=0** in this particular line??

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,  y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scikit-learn random state in splitting dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191717/scikit-learn-random-state-in-splitting-dataset)

Answer (score 1):

Random state is a parameter to fix the way the data is being sampled. Therefore, if you want to reproduce the same model you choose any value for `random_state` and next time you run your code you will get the same data split.

Example
you have a `list1=[1,2,3,4]` , let's say you can add to it a `random_state` for permutation,  for `random_state=0` the list1 will be `[2,3,4,1]`, for `random_state=2` it could be `[3,1,4,2]` etc... same thing for `X_train` `X_test` etc...

Each random number you input will give a different split.

Answer (score 0):

`random_state` simply sets a seed to the random generator, so that your train-test splits are always deterministic. If you don't set a seed, it is different each time.

[documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split):

> ***`random_state`*** : ***`int`, `RandomState` instance or `None`, optional
> (default=`None`)***
> If `int`, `random_state` is the seed used by the random
> number generator; If `RandomState` instance, `random_state` is the random
> number generator; If `None`, the random number generator is the
> `RandomState` instance used by `np.random`.