# Problems with the random-state parameter on data splitting with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

When I look for the random -state parameter in sklearn's documentation, this is what I find:

**random_state : int or RandomState
    Pseudo-random number generator state used for random sampling.**

I don't understand very well what it is.

The accuracy for different classifiers changes notably depending on the number I write on the random-state parameter. Why is that? Which number should I set?

It is my first time on a Machine Learning project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random state (Pseudo-random number)in Scikit learn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-numberin-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `random_state` parameter ensures that your data are split in exactly the same manner each time you run your code. This practice is important when you want to compare the accuracy of different models (e.g. different algorithms or additional features, or both): if you keep shuffling the deck in different ways while testing new approaches, how are you to know whether the increase or decrease in accuracy is due to the changes you've made to your model, versus being due to using slightly different train and test datasets?

As far as choosing the number for your `random_state` parameter: that's up to you. Some experiment with different values of the parameter and see for which `random_state` value the model performs best. It really depends on your application: is this a production-scale machine-learning model you're developing, or is it a model for a data science challenge? In the former case, it shouldn't matter much. In the latter case, I have known people who tune their model completely and then begin experimenting with different `random_state` parameters to bump up their accuracies. I don't necessarily agree with that practice, because it seems like another form of overfitting (see more [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263999/is-random-state-a-parameter-to-tune). I usually choose `100` because that number is funny to me -- there's really no logic behind it. Some people choose `42`, others `1`, etc.

See a more detailed example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-numberin-scikit-learn).

Comment: I have already read the documentation you've passed me. However, I'm afraid I'm not clear on which random-state number should i set.

Thank you for your speed!

Comment: @BorjaFernándezAntelo Did you even read what I wrote? I detail in the second paragraph how you go about "choosing" your `random_state` parameter.