# What is "random-state" in sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split example?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, random, scikit-learn

Can someone explain me what `random_state` means in below example?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Why is it hard coded to 42?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random state (Pseudo-random number) in Scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-number-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Isn't that obvious? 42 is the [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#Popular_culture).

On a serious note, `random_state` simply sets a seed to the random generator, so that your train-test splits are always deterministic. If you don't set a seed, it is different each time.

[Relevant documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split):

> ***`random_state`*** : ***`int`, `RandomState` instance or `None`, optional
>   (default=`None`)***
>   If `int`, `random_state` is the seed used by the random
>   number generator; If `RandomState` instance, `random_state` is the random
>   number generator; If `None`, the random number generator is the
>   `RandomState` instance used by `np.random`.

Comment: That first sentence was more than enough.

Comment: @cs95 Do I have to generate a new `random_state` for subsequent methods in my code? For example, if I set the random state as 42 for the `train_test_split`, do I set the random state also as 42 for the classifier I will be using on the split data? What about if I want to compare two different classifiers, do I use the same random state for both classifiers?

Comment: @Turtle I think you are looking to set a global seed so your pipeline is deterministic. This will only make the split deterministic, nothing else. Consider using something like np.random.seed or creating a random state object that is then reused across functions.

Comment: but if you use it in train, test split do you still need to use it when you run each algorithm ?

Comment: How is the random_state saved? For example does it matter if I run my code on different Colab-Notebooks on different accounts?

Comment: I think the spec dictates that the seed be deterministic across platforms @MaxlGemeinderat but all bets are off the table if random seed is `None`.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't specify the random_state in the code, then every time you run(execute) your code a new random value is generated and the train and test datasets would have different values each time.

However, if a fixed value is assigned like random_state = 0 or 1 or 42 or any other integer then no matter how many times you execute your code the result would be the same .i.e, same values in train and test datasets.

Answer (score 10):

Random state ensures that the splits that you generate are reproducible. Scikit-learn uses random permutations to generate the splits. The random state that you provide is used as a seed to the random number generator. This ensures that the random numbers are generated in the same order.

Answer (score 6):

When the Random_state is not defined in the code for every run train data will change and accuracy might change for every run.
When the Random_state = " constant integer" is defined then train data will be constant For every run so that it will make easy to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The random state is simply the lot number of the set generated randomly in any operation. We can specify this lot number whenever we want the same set again.