# The prediction accuracies resulted from random forest regression models change each time I run the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Every time I run the RF model from the begining I got different accuracies I have run the following code:

```
df17_tmp1 = df17_tmp.sample(frac=6, replace = True).reset_index(drop=True)
    
x_3d = df17_tmp1[col_in_3d] # Features;  
y_3d = df17_tmp1['over/under_exc_vol(m3)'].values  # Target
   
# In[29]:
   
x_train_3d, x_test_3d, y_train_3d, y_test_3d = train_test_split(x_3d, y_3d, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
   
# # train RF

# In[30]:

x_train_3d = x_train_3d.fillna(0).reset_index(drop = True)
x_test_3d = x_test_3d.fillna(0).reset_index(drop = True)

y_train_3d[np.isnan(y_train_3d)] = 0
y_test_3d[np.isnan(y_test_3d)] = 0

rf_3d = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 70, random_state = 42)
rf_3d.fit(x_train_3d, y_train_3d)

# # Predict with RF and evaluate

# In[31]:

prediction_3d = rf_3d.predict(x_test_3d)
mse_3d = mean_squared_error(y_test_3d, prediction_3d)
rmse_3d = mse_3d**.5
abs_diff_3d = np.array(np.abs((y_test_3d - prediction_3d)/y_test_3d))
abs_diff_3d = abs_diff_3d[~np.isinf(abs_diff_3d)]

mape_3d = np.nanmean(abs_diff_3d)*100
accuracy_3d = 100 - mape_3d
```

I got the following results in terms accuracies:

85.94 /
85.71/
85.83 /
82.64 /
86.56 /
85.24 /
83.40 /
82.39 /
84.98 /
83.81 /

So, is that normal? and which accuracy should be considered?

Comment: Yes, what do you think think the word "Random" in "RandomForest" means?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy truth is, they set an explicit `random_state`, both in `RandomForestRegressor()` and in `train_test_split()`. Seems the issue is in `df17_tmp.sample`, which seems to invoke the RNG without a seed being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you set a `random_state` in your `train_test_split()` to generate a deterministic split and in the `RandomForestRegressor()`
which would control the randomness within the algorithm, the difference is occurring due to the **random sampling** you are applying to your dataframe here:

```
df17_tmp1 = df17_tmp.sample(frac=6, replace = True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

You should replace the above line with the following:

```
df17_tmp1 = df17_tmp.sample(frac=6, replace = True, random_state = 42).reset_index(drop=True)
```

to get the same output on every run.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147774/what-is-random-state-in-sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split-example) to learn more.

Comment: No worries! Happy learning!