# 100% error rate on test set with one class svm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to detect outlier images. But I'm getting bizarre results from the model.

I've read in the images with cv2, flattened them into 1d-arrays, and turned them into a pandas dataframe and then fed that into the SVM.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import pandas as pd
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn import *
import seaborn as sns`
```

load the labels and files

```
labels_wt = np.loadtxt("labels_wt.txt", delimiter="\t", dtype="str")
files_wt = np.loadtxt("files_wt.txt", delimiter="\t", dtype="str")`
```

load and flatten the images

```
wt_images_tmp = [cv2.imread(file) for file in files_wt]
wt_images = [image.flatten() for image in wt_images_tmp]
tmp3 = np.array(wt_images)
mutant_images_tmp = [cv2.imread(file) for file in files_mut]
mutant_images = [image.flatten() for image in mutant_images_tmp]
tmp4 = np.array(mutant_images)


X = pd.DataFrame(tmp3) #load the wild-type images
y = pd.Series(labels_wt)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42) 
X_outliers = pd.DataFrame(tmp4)
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.15, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.0001)
clf.fit(X_train)
```

Then I evaluate the results according to the sklearn tutorial on oneclass SVM.

```
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_outliers = clf.predict(X_outliers)
n_error_train = y_pred_train[y_pred_train == -1].size
n_error_test = y_pred_test[y_pred_test == -1].size
n_error_outliers = y_pred_outliers[y_pred_outliers == 1].size

print(n_error_train / len(y_pred_train))
print(float(n_error_test) / float(len(y_pred_test)))
print(n_error_outliers / len(y_pred_outliers))`
```

my error rates on the training set have been variable (10-30%), but on the test set, they have never gone below 100%. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are setting `random_state = 42`, this is biasing your `train_test_split` to always have the same splitting pattern. You can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-number-in-scikit-learn) answer. Don't specify any state and run the code again, so:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

This will show different results. Once you are sure this works, make sure yo then do [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-cv-indices-py), possibly using k-fold validation. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I removed the random state and didn't see improvement unfortunately. I even altered the nu. I re-wrote the code to do a gridsearch and I'm working on that now. hopefully, something will come up.