# random_states parameter in Machine Learning Models

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, random-seed

I have seen ML tutorials using a parameter called `random_states`. Why and how this parameter can make changes in the model?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

melbourne_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

melbourne_model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [random-state-pseudo-random-number-in-scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-number-in-scikit-learn)?

Comment: "*I was recently on a course on Intro to ML on kaggle, where I came across a tutorial on ML Model, in which they used [this and that] - Thanking you*" makes for more **noise** than signal in the question (edited out); in the future, please avoid unnecessary & irrelevant intros, storytelling, thanks etc, and focus only on the issue. Clutter does not help - on the contrary, it is unhelpful and annoying.

Comment: Ok, will take care of it... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `random_state` parameter essentially acts as a "seed." Because some ML models depend on random number generation to do things like initialize variables or optimize functions, sometimes training the same algorithm on the same data twice will yield different parameters if they were initialized differently or optimized differently. To control this, engineers will set the `random_state` parameter to a constant for repeatability purposes.